# ¿Cómo sincronizar una base de datos SQL con la datastore de googl cloud platform?

Tags: c#, sql, json, webservice, google-cloud-platform

Quiero crear un web service en C# que me permita copiar algunas (o todas) las tablas de una base de datos que tengo en local a la datastore de google. Entiendo que google trabaja de manera diferente, Hasta ahora, solo solicito los datos del SQL y genero y json, pero quiero que con ese Json pueda insertar una entidar en la Datastore de google

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que transformar los datos, realizando un proceso ETL
Sí, DataStore es una NoSQL Document Base, pero las migraciones no son tan transparentes como si fuera MongoDB, para realizar esto, te recomiendo utilizar DataFlow, que es un excelente framework para migrar datos, y realizar este tipo de procesos.

Sí buscas algo más sencillo, o acorde a este paradigma podrías usar FireBase o FireStore, igual una NoSQL Document Base, pero no tan extricta en su forma de trabajar. :)

Comment: Que tal Chaotic, viendo que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y esta basado en opiniones te recomendaria que evites contestarla ya que se espera una buena respuesta para una buena pregunta(clara y concreta, a un problema en especifico)